# -MAUI Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'KeyRoutedEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, .net, maui

I am making a MAUI application where I want to detect when the user presses specific keys.
I created a KeyDown event but KeyRoutedEventArgs is not recognized even if I have
`using System.Windows.Input;`

```
public void KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is Windows-specific code. Will only work on Windows.

```
#if WINDOWS
.. ..
#endif
```

You’ll need that both around the using, and the method itself.

Or put the code in the Windows folder. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code

---

NOTE: Maui does not yet have general keyboard support cross-platform: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3739.

Cross-platform, keys can be typed when an Entry has focus, via Entry’s members. This allows an on-screen keyboard to appear, on devices that lack physical keyboard.

Comment: which using I should put in the #if because I put 
using System.Windows.Input; and it says 'KeyRoutedEventArgs' could not be found

Comment: It can’t be found on other platforms, such as Android. So you have to also put #if around the code you showed.